# Understanding Synchronized method example in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading this link .
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html.

The example is :

```
public class Counter{

  long count = 0;

   public synchronized void add(long value){
     this.count += value;
     System.out.println("Thread="+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"value ="+count);
   }
}

public class CounterThread extends Thread{

 protected Counter counter = null;

 public CounterThread(Counter counter){
    this.counter = counter;
 }

 public void run() {
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       counter.add(i);
    }
 }
}


public class Jenkov2 {

public static void main(String[] args){
  Counter counter = new Counter();
  Thread  threadA = new CounterThread(counter);
  Thread  threadB = new CounterThread(counter);


  threadA.start();
  threadB.start();      
}
 }
```

When in run this on my system ,it always gives fixed output.

```
    Thread=9value =0
    Thread=9value =1
    Thread=9value =3
    Thread=9value =6
    Thread=9value =10
    Thread=9value =15
    Thread=9value =21
    Thread=9value =28
    Thread=9value =36
    Thread=9value =45
    Thread=10value =45
    Thread=10value =46
    Thread=10value =48
    Thread=10value =51
    Thread=10value =55
    Thread=10value =60
    Thread=10value =66
    Thread=10value =73
    Thread=10value =81
    Thread=10value =90
```

I run it multiple times but output is always same.
I was expecting it to be switching between the two threads, value will be 90 after both the threads are done.
As per me it will be like this :
thread A run method is called, i is 0, 0 will be add and as method is synchronized,it will return after adding zero,then before next iteration of i inside for loop,context switching may occur and thread B runs and value 0 will be added.

Is my understanding correct and the output can also vary between threads  or i am missing some concept.

Comment: The `run` method has no time delay. At the time where you call `threadB.start()` (or at the time where it actually starts), the first thread may already have finished. Add something like `Thread.sleep(1000);` and see if things change. The `synchronized` keyword blocks the whole method for other threads as long as one thread is inside it.

Comment: Running for loop for long duration say 10000 may lead to context switch between threads ?

Comment: Possible. There is nothing in your code that would prevent context switching. Try to increase the time the threads spend **outside** the `add` method, for example with `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

Comment: calling sleep is like enforcing context switch ??

Comment: There is also `Thread.yield()` if all you want to do is force a context switch.

Comment: @NikhilSaxena The question is *why should it switch context* if the method is super fast? Context switching itself is expensive. You need to do something to increase the chances. The longer the method takes, the more likely will be a context switch. If a thread doesn't enter the method for a longer time, then it's a good idea for the system to let another thread enter. And counting from `0` to `10` with no delay is extremely super fast. This will be executed in like *no time*.

Comment: Yes, normally you wouldn't want to call `Thread.yield()` for any reason.  For an example program I think it's fine though, just to give the user some output to see the switch.

Comment: However, if you call sleep, make sure to do it outside the synchronized method, or it will still keep the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Each time one of your threads goes around its loop, it releases the lock, and then *immediately* tries to lock it again.

Looks like on *your* system, the locking mechanism has no "fairness" to it, and the thread that just let go of the lock is able to grab it again before the other thread even knows it was released.

It could behave differently on some other system.  But then again, you never know.

Change your `run()` method if you want to try what @Zabuza suggested,

```
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        counter.add(i);
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
 }
```

The sleep call will give the other thread a chance to wake up and grab the lock.

Comment: Note that sleep time is meastures in milliseconds, so sleeping 10 milliseconds will most likely not change much.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer, Ten milliseconds is enough time for a typical desktop/server processor to run millions of instructions.  And more importantly, it's ten milliseconds during which the previously active thread is not runnable while the other thread _is_ runnable.  That's a huge change from the original situation where the first thread to win the lock stays runnable until it has completed all ten loops.